# Android WebView and executing javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a html file that looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
     This is a test
    <script>
    function testingConsole() {
    console.log("Reached end of Body");
    }
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">testingConsole();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my code looks like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chart);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvChart);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Chart/chart.html");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.loadUrl("javascript:testingConsole();");
}
```

The html file is loading fine and the text "This is a test" is displayed in my WebView. And the script testingConsole(); is execuded by itself as it should be since html file is calling it. But when I call it from my code I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: testingConsole is not defined at null:1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `loadUrl(String)` method does not execute synchronously; the `WebView` does work on other threads to load the page and parse and execute any JavaScript in it.

You should create an implementation/subclass of `WebViewClient` that overrides `onPageFinished(WebView, String)` and listen for the webview to complete the load of "chart.html". Then you can call the second `loadUrl` with your JavaScript in it, and I bet it will work. I haven't tested this, so let me know if it does.

Comment: I did a bit faster temporary version, I executed the javascript on a click of a button when I know the html loaded, and it works! Thanks man!

Comment: it loads the page in a loop !